# set canvas as the html page in processing js

Tags: javascript, processing.js

In processing javascript, you do something like this to add an animation:

```
<html>

...
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
...
<script>
var sketch=function(processingInstance){
    with(processingInstance)
    {
        size();
        ...
    }
}
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas")
var processingInstance=new Processing(canvas,sketch);
</script>
</html>
```

With the above code, I start a canvas that lays between html elements. How do I set canvas AS the html page? I want to have whatever I draw lays directly on top of my html.

Comment: You can set the canvas as the width and height of the screen, and give the canvas the highest `z-index`. For example, let's say all of your elements' `z-index` is 0. So you can make your canvas `z-index: 1` Which would render your canvas on top of all of the other elements. Another thing you'd have to do is make sure your canvas's background color is not transparent so elements don't appear below it.

Comment: Please note that Processing.js was discontinued in December 2018. For new code, please consider https://p5js.org instead.